# What is the explanation or justification for this Vulcanesque Klingon name in Star Trek: Discovery?

Tags: star-trek, names, klingon, vulcan, star-trek-discovery

It has recently come to light that there will be a recurring character in [*Star Trek: Discovery*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_Discovery) named **T'Kuvma** who is

> A Klingon leader who is looking to unite the Klingon houses.

This seems like a decidedly Vulcan name.   (There are 21 names starting with **T'** [listed in Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Category:Vulcans).)    While there are [Klingon names](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Category:Klingons) with that property, they are exceedingly rare among Klingons we've encountered before.   Furthermore, it appears very atypical for Klingons to have three-syllable names or for Klingon males to have names ending in a vowel, particularly **a**. (A hard consonant is the norm.)

So, what is the explanation or justification for this Klingon name either in- or out-of-universe?
(Or is none needed?)

Comment: Maybe it's the Klingon equivalent of "A Boy Named Sue", parents gave their son a Vulcan name so he'd be beat up a lot and become a great warrior.

Comment: This seems **highly** speculative especially since the show isn't even on the air yet.

Comment: There are also a number of **Klingon** names starting with T'  http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Klingons

Comment: @Paulie_D:   I acknowledged and linked that myself.   But wouldn't you agree that **T'Vis**, **T'Kar**, and **T'Greth** are not qualitatively the same as **T'Kuvma** for the reasons I gave ?

Comment: I'm looking forward to:   ["  'Ello, T'Kuvma "](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Ello%20Guvna)

Comment: We don't have a representative sample of Klingon names to call anything *atypical*. As I said, this is **highly** speculative for something we know nothing about yet.

Comment: Out of the few hundred names klingons in the Star Trek universe, several have names beginning with t'. At the very least that makes it an *unusual* name, but not an *unheard-of* name. A bit like having a name that [starts with the letter Y](http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview/id/347668.html) in Western society

Comment: @Valorum, I think your example is more apt than you intended because your own link lists the the following names starting with Y: Yvonne, Yolanda, Yvette, Yesenia, Young, which are all feminine and/or foreign (Young excepted?) --  which is kind of exactly the same point I was making: female or Vulcan!

Comment: Consider the male captain K'Nera, the male T'Gath, and the male Klingon composer Keedera. That's two male names ending in a vowel, and one male name starting with a T'. We also see a male name with three syllables. Of the 193 Klingon name listed on Memory Alpha, we have 3 that start with T', meaning that it occurs in 1.5% of known Klingon names. For comparison, look at BehindTheName.com. Out of 3912 American names, three of them start with a double AA, which isn't common, but one of those is Aaron, which is a pretty common name in itself.

Comment: There are 47 library computer entries for "[Darmok](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/202.htm)", ranging from a legendary hunter to a frozen dessert.  In a big galaxy, these coincidences happen.

Answer (score 1):

It appears T'Kuvma is just another name. Here's a brief list of named Klingons in *Discovery*

- [L'rell](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/L%27Rell)
- [Voq](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Voq)
- [Kol](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Kol_(Klingon))
- [Dennas](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Dennas)

We also have prior Klingon names that start with `T'` ([T'Vis](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/T%27vis)) and names ending in `a` ([Noggra](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Noggra), [H'Ta](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/H%27ta))

There don't appear to be any naming conventions (let alone [appearance conventions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/170386/why-do-the-klingons-in-star-trek-discovery-look-so-different?rq=1)) for Klingons.