# Are there starships in Star Trek that we know are named after men?

Tags: star-trek, spaceship, names

This question:

[Are there starships in Star Trek that we know are named after women?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/180484/are-there-starships-in-star-trek-that-we-know-are-named-after-women/180515#180515)

inspires me to ask about starships that we know are named after men.  If the name of a starship is an Earth surname, it is natural for contemporary audiences to assume it is named after a famous Earth **MAN** with that surname living before the present (2018 at the moment).  But it is also possible that the ship might be named after a famous woman with that surname, possibly one living between the present and the era(s) of Star Trek.

So how many starships in *Star Trek* are certainly named after men?

Comment: define "starship". Also - only the shows tagged or do you mean for the entire canon (film/tv) body of work?

Comment: Many; http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Federation_starships

Comment: USS Agamemnon, USS Ajax, USS Albert Einstein, USS Apollo, USS Archer, USS Armstrong etc etc. It's probably easier to ask which starships *aren't* named after men or male gods

Comment: @Valorum.   Yeah.  And many are undeniably unambiguous:  USS Albert Einstein, USS James Fennimore Cooper, USS John F Kennedy, USS Neil Armstrong, USS Neils Bohr, USS Robert Louis Stevenson, USS Sherlock Holmes, USS Yuri Gagarin

Comment: @Valorum I was even compiling a list of all male-named ships

Comment: @MatthewBarclay - Meh. I struggled to care. A simple search would have revealed the answer (see below) in less than a few seconds.

Comment: Adjusting tags.

Answer (score 8):

There are many per the [list](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Federation_starships) linked by @Valorum.

But the following are quite **unambiguous**:

- USS Albert Einstein
- USS Crazy Horse
- USS Elmer Fudd
- USS Farouk El-Baz
- USS James Fennimore Cooper
- USS John F. Kennedy
- USS John Muir
- USS Max Plank  <sup>[sic s/b *Planck*]</sup>
- USS Neil Armstrong
- USS Neils Bohr
- USS Robert Louis Stevenson
- USS Sherlock Holmes
- USS Thomas Paine
- USS Yuri Gagarin

This is not even including those that are almost certainly supposed to be named after **male mythological entities**:

> E.g. Apollo, Hermes, Prometheus, Ulysses

And not including those that are almost certainly supposed to be named after notable historical surnames that are almost certainly supposed to be based on specific **male historical figures**:

> E.g. **Archer**, **Armstrong**, **Bradbury**, Chekov, **Cochrane**, Cooper, **Copernicus**, Cortez, Crockett, **Drake**, **Edison**,  Farragut, Fleming, **Glenn**, **Gorkon**, **Grissom**, **Hood**, Hoover, Horatio, Kelvin, **Korolev**, Livingston, **Magellan**, Nash, Pasteur, Potemkin, Profokiev, Roosevelt, Rutledge, **Sarek**, **Shepard**, **Shran**, Suleiman, Tolstoy, Truman, Tsiolkovsky, Tycho, Wellington, Yamaguchi, **Yeager**.

Here I've bolded certain names that, because their association with astronomy, discovery, aeronautics, or their origin in the *Star Trek* universe, I consider to be obviously based on the obvious well-known male figure.

<sup>(I mean, come on.   We don't know there wasn't a 22nd century Andorian woman named Elmer Fudd either so I don't see why we should consider a full name to be any more conclusive than *Shran*, *Sarek*, or *Yeager*)</sup>

Comment: USS Grissom, from *Wrath of Khan*, surely named after American astronaut "Gus" Grissom, one of the Apollo 1 victims.

Comment: The DaVinci from the Corps of Engineers books

Comment: @ZeissIkon - Unless it's named after Shannon Grissom, the famous artist.

Comment: @ZeissIkon There are a LOT of starships whose names **almost certainly** come from a man's last name, but the OP explicitly stated that they wouldn't accept last names as evidence as the name could be shared with a (presumably yet to become famous) woman.

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish:   Well, yeah, I said I *didn't include* them  :)    No harm to extra info.

Comment: @ThePopMachine Your answer has my upvote for putting the unambiguous cases at the top. I was just trying to explain why the *Grissom* didn't belong among them.

Comment: @ZeissIkon --- Grissom appears in The Search for Spock, not The Wrath of Khan. Still a good observation, though,

Comment: Kirk's first posting was to the U.S.S. Farragut, undoubtedly a reference to Admiral David Farragut. Farragut is famous for coining the phrase "Damn the torpedoes, full speed ahead", which is oddly appropriate, considering.